# 2分探索木の削除アルゴリズム

Tags: java, アルゴリズム

２分探索木のアルゴリズム実装課題で悩んでいます。
追加、探索までは実装でき、テストもokだったのですが、削除だけうまくいきません。
実装したい削除メソッドの構造は、

- (a),(b),(c)で場合分けして削除する
  (a)削除するkeyの節点が葉
  (b)削除するkeyの節点が１つのみ子を持つ
  (c)削除するkeyの節点が２つの子を持つ
- 探索メソッドと同様削除する値を探索し、探索が失敗した場合エラーメッセージ

場合分けしたところまでは良いものの、実際に値を削除する方法がわかりません
削除したいノード=nullをしても値は削除されません

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    private Node root = null; // 根

    private class Node {
        private int key; // key
        private Node left; // 左の子
        private Node right; // 右の子

        private Node(int key) {
            this.key = key;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("<%s(%d)%s>", (left == null ? "/" :
                left), key, (right == null ? "/" : right));
        }
    }

    public void add(int x) {
        Node v = root; // 探索中のノードを指すカーソル
        Node p = null; // 探索中のノードの親を指すカーソル
        boolean isLeft = true; // ノードpの左の子を参照したならtrue, 右の子を参照したならfalse
        Node nn = new Node(x); // 新たに追加するkey値をもつノード
        while (v != null) { //葉に到達していないことを表す
            if (x < v.key) {
                p = v;
                isLeft = true;
                v = v.left;
            }else{
                p = v;
                isLeft = false;
                v = v.right;
            }
        }
        if (v == root) root = nn;
        else if (isLeft) p.left = nn;
        else p.right = nn;
    }

    //課題追加部分:探索アルゴリズム
    //探索が成功すれば真を、失敗すれば偽を返す
    public boolean search(int x){
        Node v = root; // 探索中のノードを指すカーソル
        boolean ret = false; //探索成功の可否の判定値
        while(v != null && !ret){ //１つ目の条件は葉に到達していないことを表す
            if(x<v.key) v = v.left; //keyが探索する値よりも大きい場合、左の子へ移動
            else if(x>v.key) v= v.right; //keyが探索する値よりも小さい場合、右の子へ移動
            else ret =true; //探索する値が見つかった時
        }
        return ret;
    }

    //質問部分！！！！
    //課題追加部分:削除アルゴリズム
    //削除するkeyの節点によって(a),(b),(c)で場合分けする
    public void delete(int x){
        Node v = root; 
        boolean ret = false; 
        while(v != null && !ret){ 
            if(x<v.key) v = v.left; 
            else if(x>v.key) v= v.right; 
            else {
                ret = true;
                if(v.left==null&&v.right==null){ //(a)削除するkeyの節点が葉
                    v = null;
                }
                else if(v.left==null||v.right==null){ //(b)削除するkeyの節点が１つのみ子を持つ

                }
                else{ //(c)削除するkeyの節点が２つの子を持つ

                }
            }
        }
        if(ret) System.out.println( x + "を削除しました.");
        else System.out.println("削除したいkeyが見つかりません.");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s",(this.root==null ? "/" :this.root));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
        System.out.println(bst);
        System.out.println("50,31,81,15,41,62,92,3,28,33,53,74,85を順に追加:");
        bst.add(50);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(31);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(81);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(15);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(41);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(62);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(92);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(3);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(28);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(33);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(53);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(74);
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.add(85);
        System.out.println(bst);

        //追加課題部分テスト:探索アルゴリズム
        System.out.println("3の探索結果:" + bst.search(3)); //探索成功
        System.out.println("11の探索結果:" + bst.search(11)); //探索失敗

        //追加課題部分テスト:削除アルゴリズム
        bst.delete(3); //(a)の場合
        System.out.println(bst);
        /*
        bst.delete(5); //(b)の場合
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.delete(81); //(c)の場合
        System.out.println(bst);
        bst.delete(91); //削除するkeyが存在しない場合
        */
    }

}
```

mainメソッド`bst.delete(3);`の実行結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

木構造データで、「節点が削除される」というのは、その木のどの節点から辿っても到達できなくなるという事です。

```
   X
 +-+-+
 |   |
 L   R
```

簡単な例で考えましょう。
図は、Xは根(root)で二つの子(LとR)を持つ節点、LとRは葉という木です。

プログラムでは、この木が３つの節点(Nodeクラスのオブジェクト)X,L,Rから構成されて、以下のような参照関係を持ちます。

```
X.left = L　'左の子
X.right = R '右の子
L.left = null  '葉なので子が無い
L.right = null '葉なので子が無い
R.left = null  '葉なので子が無い
R.right = null '葉なので子が無い
```

この木からRを削除するには、Rにnullを代入するのではなく、Xの右の子(X.right)をnullにします。
そうすることで、Xは右の子を持たない節点になりますから、Rが削除された事になるのです。

p.s.
X.right=null としても、Rという節点が残っているように思われるかもしれません。
実際、計算機のメモリ上には一時的に残るのですが、どこからも参照されないメモリ領域はゴミ(garbage)という印が付けられ、後に再利用されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！addメソッドと同様に親ノードを定義したらうまくいきました！